# React Native API Fetch not happening completely. Error getting thrown while mapping

Tags: api, react-native, expo

I am getting the following error while running my app. I don't know what's the problem over here. Can you please help resolve the error. Earlier the app was running smoothly, but with frequent runs the app stopped working completely. Please please please help.
The error is:

**Device: (78:22) TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...articles.map...')
This error is located at:
    in Files
    in t
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in f
    in RCTView
    in f
    in C
    in t
    in n
    in RCTView
    in n
    in RCTView
    in f
    in S
    in t
    in n
    in RCTView
    in t
    in t
    in l
    in s
    in r
    in App
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in n
    in n
    in v
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in c
This error is located at:
    in r
    in App
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in n
    in n
    in v
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in c**

```html
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Button} from 'react-native';
import {Header, Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import Contents from './Contents';




import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createNavigatorContainer 
} from "react-navigation";

const API = 'https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/d25403ba73f5';

export default class Files extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      articles: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ articles: data }));
  }
  
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'FILES',
    style:{display:'flex',
    flexDirection:'row',
    backgroundColor:"#FFD700",
    flex:1}
  };
  render() {

  const { articles } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container2}>
      <View style={styles.innerview2}>
       {articles.map(articles =>
        <ScrollView>
        
          <TouchableOpacity key={articles.ID} 
           style={styles.scrollView2}
           onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Contents', {
            
              id:articles.ID, 
              date:articles.Date, 
              title:articles.Title, 
              content: articles.Content, 
              category: articles.Category,
              
            })}
          >
            <Text>{articles.Title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </ScrollView>
        )}
        
        </View>
        <Button title="Refresh"/>
      </View>
    );
    
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container2: {
    flex:1,
    display:'flex',
    flexDirection:'column'
  },
  scrollView2:{
    display:'flex',
    flexDirection:'column',
    backgroundColor:'#DDA8F4'
  },
  innerview2:{
    flex: 1,
    padding: 30,
    display:'flex',
    flexDirection:'column'
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you receive from the API request? Are you sure that you are receiving an array? If you receive an object or a string -  `.map()` is not a method of them and it's normal to throw an error.

Comment: @HristoEftimov Ive edited the code. You can check the API from there

Comment: unfortunatelly, I cannot reproduce the problem. I've created an Snack example: https://snack.expo.io/SJ-SeBAPV and it works fine. I guess this is not the whole logic of the screen... is there something that you didn't paste here? Maybe the problem is coming from there :/

Comment: Looking at your code, you should log 'data' inside the second 'then' of your fetch call, i,.e. where you're setting state. I assume this is undefined, thus your error.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@vshiva2306/intrigued-edamame can you please check and try with this snack link?

Comment: @HristoEftimov snack.expo.io/@vshiva2306/intrigued-edamame can you please check and try with this snack link?

Comment: @LeeBrindley snack.expo.io/@vshiva2306/intrigued-edamame can you please check and try with this snack link?

Comment: Your API request doesn't go to the catch method, but the response returns `{type:"default",status:404,ok:false,headers:{…},url:"https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0bu/46ea903f642a",_bodyInit:"{"error":"Not such route /apis/v1.0bu/46ea903f642a"}",_bodyText:"{"error":"Not such route /apis/v1.0bu/46ea903f642a"}"}` Please, chec kyour API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cover the unsuccessful response.

If you try to log your articles

```
  const { articles } = this.state;
  console.log(this.state);
```

You can see the following error

```
articles:{error:"Not such route /apis/v1.0bu/46ea903f642a"}
```

Then you go further and log the response:

```
fetch(API)
  .then(response => { console.log(response); return response.json() })
```

That produces

```
{
  type:"default",
  status:404,
  ok:false,
  headers:{…},
  url:"https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0bu/46ea903f642a",
  _bodyInit:"{"error":"Not such route /apis/v1.0bu/46ea903f642a"}",
  _bodyText:"{"error":"Not such route /apis/v1.0bu/46ea903f642a"}"
}
```

As you can see the API responds with 404. You need to cover that case and populate `articles` state only on successful response.